# Can't get async task to work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was calling a class which was performing network operations on the main thread, causing my app to blow up on more recent devices. So I've tried moving the call to the class into a AsyncTask inner class in my main activity. However now i'm getting null reference expections.

Here's my AsyncTask:

```
      private class RetreiveAmazonNodesXML extends AsyncTask {

        private Exception exception;

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
               try {
                    childrenBrowseNodesXml = new Amazon(browseNodeId, locality);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.exception = e;
                }
            return null;
        }


     }
```

And here's where I call it in my activity:

```
 RetreiveAmazonNodesXML test = new RetreiveAmazonNodesXML();
 test.execute();
 parseXmlFile(childrenBrowseNodesXml.getBrowseNodesXML());
```

childrenBrowseNodesXml isn't getting updated and returning null. I know my Amazon class works fine so its something im doing with AsyncTask, but I have no idea?

Comment: have a look at my example here about how to execute an Async task and how to get its result in a callback function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713751/json-object-null-android-asynctask/13713852#13713852

Comment: Your code prevents you to see if there's an exception thrown. Put some log in your catch Exception (or better, [remove this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception)).

Comment: Pass generic tag, class RetreiveAmazonNodesXML extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>.

Comment: You need normally async task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're trying to use the value that `AsyncTask` hasn't returned, as `AsyncTask` is running **asyncronously**.

You should put `parseXmlFile(childrenBrowseNodesXml.getBrowseNodesXML());` into your `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method, like this:

```
  private class RetreiveAmazonNodesXML extends AsyncTask {

    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
           try {
                childrenBrowseNodesXml = new Amazon(browseNodeId, locality);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {

           parseXmlFile(childrenBrowseNodesXml.getBrowseNodesXML());

    }

 }
```

Also, `return null` in `doInBackground` method may not be a good manner, the stuff that `doInBackground` returns will be passed as a parameter to `onPostExecute()` method automatically by `AsyncTask`.

For more about the `AsyncTask`, please refer to the [Android Developers: AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: this did the trick thanks! should of known it would be something to do with multi-threading messing my code up again. Had to add more code to onPostExecute, which has now resulted in a problem with a spinner not updating...eurgh!

Answer (score 2):

Use callback for get result from async task. Here interface callback class:

```
public interface Callback {
    public void onSuccess(Object data);
    public void onError(String errorMsg);
}
```

And create instance this class and implement its:

```
final Callback resCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
public void onSuccess(Object data) {
    parseXmlFile(data);
}

@Override
public void onError(String errorMsg) {
    //show error with Alert or Toast
}
};
```

And create asynctask class with your callback:

```
RetreiveAmazonNodesXML test = new RetreiveAmazonNodesXML(resCallback);
test.execute(yourObjectsParams);
```

Write asynctask class like this:

```
private class RetreiveAmazonNodesXML extends AsyncTask {
    private Callback responderCallback;
    private Exception exception;

    public GeneralHttpTask(Callback callback){
        this.responderCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
           try {
                Amazon childrenBrowseNodesXml = new Amazon(browseNodeId, locality);
                return childrenBrowseNodesXml;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if(result != null) {
            responderCallback.onSuccess(result);
        } else {
            responderCallback.onError(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wondering what's the benifit of a callback interface when AsyncTask provides onPostExecute()?

Comment: Example you want use general AsyncTask class in more activities yes, then you need create a general AsyncTask class and send its url and callback, when callback come then you make use result. If you want separately create AsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you create a background thread (`AsyncTask`) that fills the childrenBrowseNodesXml after a while (when it's actually executed), but you try to use it immediately in your activity code.

Move your parseXMLFile to `onPostExecute(Void result)` method of AsyncTask instead.